# React w Gatsby: Why is that my font file is downloaded twice sometimes

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, frontend, gatsby

I am developing a website using Gatsby with React. And I found that every time I refresh the page, there is 1.6 MB / 1.6 MB resources loaded. I am kind of new to web development so I don't really know whether this is a lot to download or it is just moderate amount.

However I do notice a problem, which is after I deploy my website on Netlify, the font file is requested twice so it is downloaded twice. 
You can see in the screenshot there were two Roboto-Light files requested.
[image]

Here is how I include the font file in my codebase.

First I set a webpack alias `'@fonts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/fonts'),`

Then in `src/styles/fonts.js` I have

```
import RobotoLight from '@fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf';
export { RobotoLight};
```

Finally in my `src/styles/GlobalStyle.js` I have

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url(${fontFamilies.RobotoLight}) format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: auto;
}
...
```

So whenever I need to apply this `RobotoLight` font I just set the element's `font-family` to be `Roboto`.

I don't know why my font is downloaded more than once and I don't know if this way of including a font is the best practice. Also I'd like to know if `1.6 MB / 1.6 MB resources` is too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is 1.6MB a lot to load on a page?

It's hard to answer as it all depends on the context. It would be a lot for a simple page without any images, but it could be little for a more complex one.
Also, in addition to page size it's worth taking into account how fast the page loads. A 2MB page may load (or seem to load) faster than a 500KB one.

> The font file is requested twice so it is downloaded twice.

From your screenshot it doesn't look like it's the case: Roboto appears on 2 rows but data seems to be downloaded only once (88.3KB).

> How to load a font in Gatsby?

The recommended way to add a Google font in Gatsby is to include a Google Fonts link element within the Helmet component. React Helmet is discussed in the [Gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-eight/#add-page-metadata).

It's also possible to add a font via CSS import at the top of your CSS file, however the font download will depend on CSS parsing, whereas a font added via Helmet will download immediately.

For reference a CSS import would look like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');
```

To use Roboto light you need to add the Roboto version with a font-weight of 300.

```
<Helmet>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet"/>
</Helmet>
```

You can then use it in your CSS:

```
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300; // Technically not needed if you load just one version of Roboto
}
```

For performance purposes it's best to load only the fonts that you use. If you also want to use the standard version of Roboto (font-weight: 400) you'd use this link instead: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! How did you tell that although Roboto appears on 2 rows but it is only downloaded once? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! The fact that there is no "size" attributed to the first of the two Roboto made me think that, but I may be wrong.